# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&) on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, buttonclick

I have to redirect to a controller action on a button click, But I'm getting this error

```
 `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).`
```

*here is my code:*

**Views/_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="tab1">
                <div class="tab2">
                    <div id="test2" class="officebar">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="current"><a href="#" rel="home">Main</a>
                                <ul>


 // ..other button code..
                          <li><span>Logout</span> 
                           <div class="button"> 
                            <a href="#" id="Logout"  title="Logout">
                                                <div class="logout">
                                                </div>
                                                Logout</a>
                                        </div>
                                       </li></ul></li>

 <script>

    $("#Logout").click("click", function () {
                    //window.refresh("./Account/Logoutview");
                   // "@Url.Action("Logoutview", "Account")";
                    window.location = "@Url.Action("Logoutview", "Account")";
                 window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Logoutview", "Account")";

                });

 </script>
```

**this is my Logoutview location:**

```
Views/Account/Logoutview
```

this is my output error, please help : 
[image]

Edit3:

I can able to hit the action method if i use

```
<li>
<div><a class="button" href="@Url.Action("Logoutview", "Account")"  title="Logout">Logout</a>
 </div></li>
```

but I need to use the above mentioned design .This is the problem.

**Solution:I tried   `window.location.href = 'Account/Logoutview';` instead of   `window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Logoutview", "Account")";`
Thankyou  user2110309, PKKG, MMohamad Bataineh for your time :)**

Comment: Can you show the generated source code for your view? I want to see what your code for those Url.Actions are generated as?

Comment: Check my Edit in the question

Comment: Can you add the code for your LogOut action too?

Comment: try using `[ValidateInput(false)]` for your Action Method.

Comment: @PKKG [ValidateInput(false)] not solving the problem. :(

Comment: I am assuming you are using this attribute for two Action Methods 1. LogOn and 2. LogOut

Comment: @PKKG I did, Still same error :(

Comment: can you show the logon action method ?

Comment: check my edit 3 please

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

This may open up risks in your application if you're not properly escaping data. What I do recommend is replacing the `&` sign with another character like `_` .

Other than that, I would try putting `[ValidateInput(false)]` on top of your action. You said it is not working for you but you may be putting it on the wrong action.

Comment: I gave another recommendation of just replacing the & sign. He can also encode it. Other than that, I don't see why [ValidateInput(false)] would not work.

Comment: @gs11111 Have you tried putting the ValidateInput above the LogoutView Action in Account

Comment: Yes  Mohamad Bataineh,Still the same error . But working when i use the edit3 code

Comment: Show us the code for `LogOutView`. Also just a wild input, try turning off caching for the page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36405/discussion-between-mohamad-bataineh-and-gs11111)